# How can I pass command line arguments to GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

How can I pass command line arguments to `ghci` in the same way as doing the below (within the GHCi prompt):

```
:set args abc xyz
```

So something like `ghci Main.hs -- abc xyz`?

Comment: What about ``:main abc xyz``?

Comment: Wouldn't `main` have to then be modified to accept those parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `.ghci` file with

```
:set args abc xyz
```

Which will be executed when executing `ghci Main.hs`.